# Stability and controllability of a system (check my answer)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, linear-control

Let´s study some control properties of the following system with $a,b,d,c > 0$ :

$$
\pmatrix{x\\y\\z\\v}'=\pmatrix{-a&a&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\d&-d&0&0\\c&0&0&0}\pmatrix{x\\y\\z\\v} + \pmatrix{0\\0\\bd\\0}u
$$

**My attempt:**

a) In terms of controllability, we can check that the controllability matrix $R(A,b) = [b|Ab|A^2b|A^3b]$ is invertible. Is there a quicker way to do this?

b) Regarding the controller form $A^{\flat}$, one could compute the eigenvalues of matrix $A$. However, we could also use the fact that $AR(A,b)=R(A,b)\hat{A}$ and $A^{\flat}R(A^{\flat}, b^{\flat})=R(A^{\flat}, b^{\flat})\hat{A}$ since $A^{\flat}$ and $A$ have the same characteristic polynomial. As a result,  $A^{\flat} = T^{-1}AT$ where $T=R(A,b)R(A^{\flat}, b^{\flat})^{-1}$. But I don't know about $A^{\flat}$.

I also wonder whether $R(A^{\flat}, b^{\flat})=I$ because it is known that $R(\hat{A},\hat{b})=I.$

c) If I am interested in finding a feedback $u = fx$ so that all eigenvalues of $A + bf$ equal $−1$, I can just impose the conditions. The system is controllable, the Pole Shifting Theorem helps with this purpose.

Comment: What is the controller form $A^{\flat}$, do you mean the [controllable canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realization_(systems)#Canonical_realizations)? And how is $\hat{A}$ defined?

Comment: Let us write $\chi(s)=s^n-\alpha_ns^{n-1}-\dots-\alpha_2s-\alpha_1$ for the characteristic polynomial of A. Then:
$\hat{A}:= \pmatrix{0&0&\dots&0&\alpha_1\\1&0&\dots&0&\alpha_2\\0&1&\dots&0&\alpha_3\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\0&0&\dots&1&\alpha_n} $ and 
$A^{\flat}:= (\hat{A})^{T}$ where $T$ denotes the matrix transpose.